# Add/Hide tags based on screen size

Tags: html, asp.net, responsive-design

I have a table that has 4 columns but on smaller devices I want it to only be 2 columns. Is there a way to add ending tags and new beginning row tags to create a new row for only smaller screens?

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="DetailTable">
  <asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell><strong>Order #:</strong></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell><asp:Label runat="server" ID="ordnumLabel"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>

    </asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow> (Add this line in only on small screens)

    <asp:TableCell><strong>Customer:</strong></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="custLabel"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
  ...
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Responsive Design.

This will be difficult with a `<table>` as you have it. Depending on the css/framework you are using, you could use `<div>`s with a grid and media queries that will resize based on the dimensions.